# Including swagger api cause conflicts in jaxb provider under JBoss EAP

Tags: java, xml, jboss, jaxb, swagger

I use JBoss 6.x EAP with RestEasy.

When I try to include swagger.io 1.5.0 in my web application and try to make a call with an external jersey rest client, I notice that it gives me error because the body request is not well parsed due to ignored @XMLElement(name="some_value") during json conversion.

This is probably due to swagger jaxb library that overrides JBoss provided libraries.

This is a piece code of the external rest client

```
// requestObject is a pojo with JAXB annotations
// When using swagger, the field @XmlElement name is ignored, therefore the object is unmashaled with myName instead of my_name as expected
// @XmlElement(name = "my_name"))
// String myName

ClientResponse response;
try {
    response = client.resource(requestURI).queryParams(queryParams)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(ClientResponse.class, requestObject);
```

I tried to include a recent version of xml provider, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

but nothing changes.

Any suggestion on how to use original jackson / jaxb providers for Object mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by using the solution provided [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/960)

Just add this set of exclusions on dependencyManagement of swagger library

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```